# Reload data with jQuery only when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there exists a solution to reload data using jQuery only when is needed to. My current script is reloading every 1 second and it is overloading the website.
My script looks like this

```js
var timeleft=100;

window.onload = function onLoad() {
setInterval("reloadinfo()",1000);
setInterval("updatetimer()",1);
};

function updatetimer() {
 var d = new Date();
    var n = 99-Math.round(d.getMilliseconds()/10);
 if(timeleft == 100) n = 0;
 if(n < 0) n = 0
 if(n < 10) $('#timeleft').text(timeleft+'.0'+n);
 else $('#timeleft').text(timeleft+'.'+n);
}

function reloadinfo() {
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "information.php",
 }).done(function (msg) {
     msg = $.trim(msg);
     if (msg != '[]') {
         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
         $("#lga").html('<img src="' + obj.ava + '" alt="avatar" width="115" height="115"></src>');
         $("#lg").text("#" + obj.name);
         $("#lgi").text(obj.age);
         $("#lgv").text('$' + obj.school);
         $("#lgc").text(obj.promo + '%');
         $("#lt").text(obj.class);
         $("#lwn").text(obj.mark);
     }
 });
}
```

I would like to use the function **reloadinfo()** only after 10 seconds the **timeleft** inside **updatetimer()** reaches 0.

Comment: If you are looking for real time technology, you should consider looking into Socket. There is a good library for that which is [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) it provides real time connection between two clients

Comment: every second is far too often - use a setTimeout in the done to call again 2 or 3 seconds after response. If you save the ETAG or similar you can send it to the server and the server can send a 304 or similar if nothing changed

Comment: If you are new to javascript or web dev in general, this is actually a relatively difficult problem that seems simple because of how common it is, as @Nicolas said, what you're looking for is called a Web Socket https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: @Nicolas thank you for the link, this will help me with other part of the project.

Comment: @Daniel I'm glad i could help, if you are planing on using Socket.IO, you should also consider reading on [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/), which is  the framework Socket.io uses for it's server side. There is a good example in the socket IO website called [Chat](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) which is a very basic real time chat. It's a good place to start if you are not familiar with socket Technology. Good luck with your project !

Answer (score 1):

You just need to nest the timers like so:

```
var timeleft=100; 
var timer;

window.onload = function onLoad() {    
    timer = setInterval(updateTimer,1); 
}; 
function updateTimer() {    
    var d = new Date(); 
    var n = 99-Math.round(d.getMilliseconds()/10); 
    if(timeleft == 100) n = 0;  
    if(n < 0) {
        n = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
        setTimeout(reloadInfo, 10000);
    }
    if(n < 10) 
        $('#timeleft').text(timeleft+'.0'+n);   
    else
       $('#timeleft').text(timeleft+'.'+n); 
} 

function reloadinfo() { 
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "information.php"
    }).done(function (msg) {
         msg = $.trim(msg);      
         if (msg != '[]') {      
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);         
              $("#lga").html('<img src="' + obj.ava + '" alt="avatar" width="115" height="115"></src>');     
              $("#lg").text("#" + obj.name);     
              $("#lgi").text(obj.age);   
              $("#lgv").text('$' + obj.school);      
              $("#lgc").text(obj.promo + '%');   
              $("#lt").text(obj.class);      
              $("#lwn").text(obj.mark);      
         }
        timer = setInterval(updateTimer,1);
    }); 
}
```

This way when the timer in `updateTimer` reaches zero you stop the count-down, After ten seconds you call `reloadInfo` and the timer will restart when `reloadInfo` has done with his http request.